# Не могу вычислить сумму полей объекта , в массиве

Tags: javascript

```
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];

let result = items.map(({ price }) => price);

const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount, index, array) => {
  let summ = 0;
  return (summ += amount);
}, 0);

console.log(calculateTotal);
```

Почему код не верный, предпологаю что на каждой итерации, **summ** прибавляется, как исправить и посчитать сумму всех **price** ?

Comment: Забыл уточнить, что важно добавить несколько проверок внутри reduce , if > 0, и if === 'number' / Внутри reduce как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не используется `total` - результат с прошлого шага. Вместо этого каждый раз создается `summ=0` к которому прибавляется `amount`. Таким образом каждый раз вычисляется `amount` а не общая сумма.

Вместо этого нужно использовать `total`

```js
const items = [{
  price: 150
}, {
  price: 150
}, {
  price: 100
}, {
  price: 100
}];

let result = items.map(({
  price
}) => price);

const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount, index, array) => {
  return total + amount;
}, 0);

console.log(calculateTotal);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];

let result = items.map(({ price }) => price);

const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount, index, array) => {  
  return (total += amount);
}, 0);

console.log(calculateTotal);
```

---

Можно сразу с объектом работать

```js
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];
const calculateTotal = items.reduce((total, item) => total += item.price, 0);

console.log(calculateTotal);
```

Comment: А можно ли в этом - items.reduce((total, item) => total += item.price, 0);    reduce - добавить несколько условий , две проверки на пример if > 0 ?

Comment: @spectre_it, callback передаваемый в reduce - это обычная функция, результат которой будет передан в качестве первого параметра на следующей итерации. Внутри функции может быть что угодно.

Comment: ниже добавил ответ, на свой вопрос. добавил внутрь функции проверку , но результат NaN . Что я не понимаю, не пойму почему не работают условия.

Comment: @spectre_it, если у тебя новый вопрос - оформи новый вопрос. Если дополнение к существующему, добавь информацию непосредственно в вопрос. Ошибка у тебя очевидная: `total` - это результат **с прошлого шага**, так как ты не всегда возвращаешь значение, иногда total становится `undefined`, и арифметические действия с ним приводят к `NaN`, который далее так и останется.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount, index, array) => {
  let summ = 0;
  return (summ += amount);
}, 0);
```

Тут вы никак не задействуете переменную `total`.
Можно переделать функцию в вашем цикле `reduce` вот так:

```js
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];

let result = items.map(({ price }) => price);

const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount, index, array) => {
  total += amount
  return total;
}, 0);
```

**Теперь всё работает.**

---

Если вам интересно как можно улучшить этот код в принципе:

Операция в функции-теле цикла настолько примитивна, что можно записать её в одну строку:

```js
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];

let result = items.map(({ price }) => price);

const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount, index, array) => {
  return total + amount;
}, 0);
```

Далее можно убрать лишние символы, которые затрудняют работу с кодом:

```js
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];

let result = items.map(({ price }) => price);

const calculateTotal = result.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount, 0);
```

Потом можно убрать лишний проход циклом по массиву:

```js
const items = [{ price: 150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 100 }, { price: 100 }];

const calculateTotal = items
  .reduce((total, amount) => total + amount.price, 0);
```